# Android updating MediaPlayer SeekBar position from Service class

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-broadcast, android-service-binding

I made a streaming MediaPlayer which runs on a separate service instead of the MainActivity. For updating the SeekBar position when user seeks the progress 
I'm using a Broadcast Receiver which tells the service about the position user has seek. After that the service fetches seek position and 
updates the current position of the SeekBar in the MainActivity.

Everything is working but when the user moves the SeekBar rapidly the service class
freezes the MainActivity's UI and some time crashes. What would be the best way of Updating the SeekBar of MainActivity from the Service class?

Code samples.,

**MainActivity,**

```
 // Set up constant ID for broadcast of seekbar position
        public static final String BROADCAST_SEEKBAR = "com.gm.sendseekbar";
        private Intent intent;

         @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar sb, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (fromUser) {
                    int seekPos = sb.getProgress();
                    intent.putExtra("seekpos", seekPos);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            }
```

**Service class**,

```
@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mp.setOnInfoListener(this);
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        }

@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // Set up receiver for seekbar change
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                ActivityMain.BROADCAST_SEEKBAR));

}

// Receive seekbar position if it has been changed by the user in the main activity
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            sendBufferStartBroadcast();
            updateSeekPos(intent);
        }
    };

    // Update seek position from Activity
    public void updateSeekPos(Intent intent) {

        int seekPos = intent.getIntExtra("seekpos", 0);
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {

            int playPositionInMillisecconds = (mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds / 100)
                    * seekPos;
            mp.seekTo(playPositionInMillisecconds);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Broadcast may not be the best way to do this because you don't want to tell every listening app that your app's seekbar has moved. Why not use Service and Activity communication? Example: http://blog.philippheckel.com/2012/06/10/android-example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging/